# Why is python this code not working?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm new to python and I need to open notepad.exe using subprocess module. The code :

```
    from subprocess import *
    call("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe")
```

doesn't seem to work. The program just runs, returns 0 but notepad doesn't open at all.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Use a String literal with prefix `r` .
The issue is you are using `\n` which represents a new line character

```
from subprocess import *
call(r"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")
```

Comment: call(r"C:\\Windows\system32\notepad.exe") works from cmd but not from PyCharm. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: call(r"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe")

Comment: What ever your full path to the file is, put as the string. You can see in windows explorer what the path to notepad.exe is. For example on my system the full path to notepad is: `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`

Comment: Also on most systems `call("notepad.exe")` should work. Your question is very system specific. In some cases you may even need to run with admin privileges. Also who ever downvoted could you please provide some context.

Comment: @Daniel: unrelated: do not use `from subprocess import *` in a non-interactive setting: it makes it harder to say where a name in the code comes from. See [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Answer (score -2):

You have an extra space in your path between C:\ and Windows.
Try:

```
from subprocess import *
call("C:\\Windows\system32\notepad.exe")
```

however best practice is to use the os.path module functions to build paths platform-independent:

`os.path.join( "C:", "Windows", "system32", "notepad.exe" )`

Comment: I find it a little weird to trying for platform independence when part of the path is `Windows`...

Comment: Of course this is just an example. In a general purpose program the path will not be hardcoded like this.. moreover by looking at the output of os.path.join on your OS you will find the right way of putting slashes

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the first code block doesn't actually fix the problem.